# Align cell heights in parallel tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tables sit next to each other and display data about two items that are being compared. Each item has a name, a category, and then a description - some descriptions (the third column) are very short (one word) and some are very long (multiple sentences). I need to align the two tables so that the row heights match up perfectly. Here's what I have so far:

[image: Picture of tables]

Notice how the first row in each table doesn't align because of the difference in heights in the row. Ideally I'd love to solve this with CSS and some kind of overflow property combined with `min-height`, but I'm not sure where to start. Thanks!

Comment: Need your code as a [mcve]. You can click the bracket button: `<>` and post your HTML, CSS, and JS/jQ there.

Comment: I would argue it doesn’t make sense to set row height to be the same as both tables represent unique data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the description text (2nd table) inside a "div" in "td" and 
make the "div" css: "overflow:auto; max-height:40%"; and make changes to the width of the table data as required for the both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `height` property to give each cell in the table a uniform height.
Setting the `overflow-wrap` property to `break-word` will break a long word that does not fit inside the cell (like supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) so it fits. You need to style it as an `inline-block` so the overflow works properly. If all else fails and there is just too much darn text in a table cell, you could set `overflow` to `hidden` to make sure that your users can at least see the content without it spilling over everything, but ideally you should set the `height` to be large enough for your data. If you need an example, let me know and I can post one.